# CSS Standardizing Background of Text

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal-7

I have a grid of objects in my Drupal sight, each with a different title. I'm making changes with CSS injector. The titles on each have a transparent background that only extends to the length of the text. 
[This is what they are currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px9OO.png)
I want the black background to continue [to the right edge of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54IYA.png) behind it.  I have tried changing the width of  but the background doesn't change. It seems that no matter how i try to change the size, the background still only fills to the length of the text. I noticed that the size is somehow set to auto, but I thought by manually changing the size, it would override that.
I also tried to add padding to the right of each text..

```
padding-right: calc(276px - 100%);
```

I thought the 100% width would be variable and subtracted from a fixed pixel amount, they would all be the same size. Unfortunately, the padding was still the same size on each title.
This is the code I currently have for the title div:

```
.tooltitle {
    background-color: rgba(17,17,17,.75);
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    left: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .5em .7em;
    display: inline;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get these title backgrounds to be the same size?

Comment: Any chance we could get a bit more code? Setting up something like this also depends on the parent of the title and the like, so a stripped down example would be nice and would lead you to an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.box {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
}

.tooltitle {
    background-color: rgba(17,17,17,.75);
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    padding-top:1rem;
    padding-bottom:1rem;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="tooltitle">Featured</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your html, but I do know that setting a `width` on inline elements doesn't work.  Again, it depends on your html, but I'll bet this will work:

```
.tooltitle {
  background-color: rgba(17,17,17,.75);
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em .7em;
}
```

With absolute positioning, you can specify being located along the bottom of the parent element.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. "setting a width on inline elements doesn't work" saved me. I've never worked with CSS before so I don't know a lot of the 'rules'.

Comment: Great, glad it worked! Three aspects of css that always seem to be the source of my troubles are: the `display` property, the `position` property, and the `float`/`clear` properties. If you are lost, fiddling with those (or reading their docs) is often the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use absolute positioning. This saves you the need of defining pixel values (though I defined some here since I don't have any content). This would work even if the size of the `div` depended on the image inside it.

```css
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.title{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(30, 30, 30, .8);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img>
  <div class="title">Title of container</div>
</div>
```